# Why would an app ever prohibit a user from adding a card as part of the Google Pay card selection flow?

Tags: android, google-pay

The documentation comment on the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#public-taskboolean-isreadytopay-isreadytopayrequest-request) method lists the following check as one of the minimum requirements to finish a transaction using the Google Pay API:

> User either has or can add a card in flow according to the specifications given in the [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/IsReadyToPayRequest).

It's not entirely clear what "can add a card in flow" means and it's not entirely clear what parts of [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/IsReadyToPayRequest) determine whether a user "can add a card in flow".

My guess is that (1) "can add a card in flow" means the Google Pay card selection sheet will show a button that allows the user to add a card to their account, and (2) setting the `IsReadyToPayRequest.existingPaymentMethodRequired` property to `false` is what communicates to Google Pay that a user "can add a card in flow".

Assuming the above two guesses are correct (please correct me if they're not ): Why would an app ever want to set the `IsReadyToPayRequest.existingPaymentMethodRequired` property to `true` and thereby prohibit a user from adding a card in flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

Setting `IsReadyToPayRequest.existingPaymentMethodRequired` to `true` allows merchants to come up with different UX patterns. They could, for example, show the Google Pay button on top of a payment method list because the user is ready to pay and therefore only a few clicks are needed to complete the purchase.

On the web, in combination with the [createButton()](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/05/updated-google-pay-button-increases-click-through-rates.html) API (which is able to display the type and last four digits of the user's most-recently used card), this could result in higher click-through rates.